# How to detect with jquery which select change

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm creating dinamically some select, importing option values and names from ajax. The select's id are like l1, l2, l(number of current select), the name of the select is its progressive number.
I have to detect which select change, i need id or name.
This is my code:

```
   $("#plus").click(function(){
                    $('#prod').append(
                        $('<div/>',{
                            'class' : 'row',
                            'id': 'r' + nplus
                        }).append(
                        $('<div/>',{
                            'class' : 'col',
                            'id': 'cl' + nplus
                        }).append(
                        $( '<select/>', {
                            'id':'l' + nplus,
                            'type': 'select',
                            'name': nplus
                        }))).append(
                        $('<div/>',{
                            'class' : 'col',
                            'id': 'cp' + nplus
                        }).append(
                        $( '<select/>', {
                            'id':'p' + nplus,
                            'type': 'select',
                            'name': nplus
                        }))).append(
                        $('<div/>',{
                            'class' : 'col',
                            'id': 'cq' + nplus
                        }).append(
                        $( '<input/>', {
                            'id':'q' + nplus,
                            'type': 'number',
                            'name': nplus
                        }))))
                    nplus++;
    });
```

To detect which select changes, I tried:

```
$("select[id^='l']").change(function(){
                    var nameselect = $(this).attr("name");
                });
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: If that's all your code, your `<select>`s don't have any `<option>`s so will never "change".  But otherwise your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/axwyebu8/.   Can you add a snippet to your question that *demonstrates* the problem?  Have a read of [mcve].

Comment: I didn't post the option but there are 3 options i don't know how to make a snippet

Comment: That's ok - edit your question and click the snippet button.  Put your html/javascript in the boxes and select jquery from the menu on the left.  Click [run] to test it then save and post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have options to your select inputs it might look like this:-

```
let nplus=0;
 $("#plus").click(function()
 {
                    $('#prod').append(
                        $('<div/>',{
                            'class' : 'row',
                            'id': 'r' + nplus
                        }).append(
                        $('<div/>',{
                            'class' : 'col',
                            'id': 'cl' + nplus
                        }).append(
                        $( '<select/>', {
                            'id':'l' + nplus,
                            'type': 'select',
                            'name': nplus
                        }).append(new Option('option 1', 'opt1', false, false)).append(new Option('Option 2', 'opt2', false, false)))).append(
                        $('<div/>',{
                            'class' : 'col',
                            'id': 'cp' + nplus
                        }).append(
                        $( '<select/>', {
                            'id':'p' + nplus,
                            'type': 'select',
                            'name': nplus
                        }).append(new Option('Option 2.1', 'opt2.1', false, false)).append(new Option('Option 2.2', 'opt2.2', false, false)))).append(
                        $('<div/>',{
                            'class' : 'col',
                            'id': 'cq' + nplus
                        }).append(
                        $( '<input/>', {
                            'id':'q' + nplus,
                            'type': 'number',
                            'name': nplus
                        }))))
                    nplus++;
    });

$(document).on('change','select', function() 
{
        let eleID = this.getAttribute('id');
        let eleName = this.getAttribute('name');
         console.log(eleID);
         console.log(eleName);
});
```

Try [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/5kdxa26o) :

//check console for id and name of the selected element :-

Comment: Thank you very much!!! That's perfect, can you explain me why my code doesn't work?

Comment: first of all options were missing in select inputs in your code. Secondly whenever dealing with dynamically loaded content use  "$(document).on('event')" instead of  "$("selector").event".

Comment: Thank you very much, the option were insered with ajax so there were in the ajax success function, but with your solution my code works fine. Thank you